# Htaccess бесконечный редирект

Tags: .htaccess

Подскажите, почему этот код уходит в бесконечный редирект:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^\z
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подскажу:

Если открываем `/index.php` =>

Переходим на `https://mysite.com/` т.к. `/` - берет DirectoryIndex,

а это `index.php` => Условие выполняем заново.